# Cordova iOS : Add method call in AppDelegate.m

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cordova, appdelegate

I am building an app with cordova/ionic for iOS
For multiple reasons we have to put code inside generated application() of AppDelegate.m.

I allready found some similar question, but no answer yet.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36792158/cordova-phonegap-ios-modify-generated-appdelegate

There is a way to do it properly with some overloading or extending ?
The simple answer is "I can edit the AppDelegate.m" but since it's a generated file in the project, i can not do it.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use runtime to add new method in AppDelegate.m

```
for example 

@interface testViewController (){
    AppDelegate *m_appDelegate;
}

@implementation testViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    m_appDelegate = [AppDelegate new];

    // add new method in AppDelegate.m
    [self addMethod];

    // call new method in AppDelegate.m
    [m_appDelegate performSelector:@selector(join)];


}

- (void)addMethod{

        BOOL addSuccess = class_addMethod([AppDelegate class], @selector(join), (IMP)happyNewYear, "v@:");

    }

    void happyNewYear(id self,SEL _cmd){
        NSLog(@"new method");

    }

    -(void)join{
        NSLog(@"in the join %s",__func__);
    }
```

hope it helps.